# Update hstore values with other hstore values

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I have a summary table that is updated with new data on a regulary basis. One of the columns is of type hstore. When I update with new data I want to add the value of a key to the existing value of the key if the key exists, otherwise I want to add the pair to the hstore.

Existing data:

```
id     sum     keyvalue
--------------------------------------
1      2       "key1"=>"1","key2"=>"1"
```

New data:

```
id    sum      keyvalue
--------------------------------------------------
1     3        "key1"=>"1","key2"=>"1","key3"=>"1"
```

Wanted result:

```
id    sum      keyvalue
--------------------------------------------------
1     5        "key1"=>"2","key2"=>"2","key3"=>"1"
```

I want to do this in a on conflict part of an insert.
The sum part was easy. But I have not found how to concatenate the hstore in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built int. You have to write a function that accepts to hstore values and merges them in the way you want.

```
create function merge_and_increment(p_one hstore, p_two hstore)
  returns hstore
as
$$
  select hstore_agg(hstore(k,v))
  from (
    select k, sum(v::int)::text as v
    from (
      select *
      from each(p_one) as t1(k,v)
      union all
      select *
      from each(p_two) as t2(k,v)
    ) x
    group by k
  ) s
$$
language sql;
```

The hstore_agg() function isn't built-in as well, but it's easy to define it:

```
create aggregate hstore_agg(hstore) 
(
  sfunc = hs_concat(hstore, hstore),
  stype = hstore
);
```

So the result of this:

```
select merge_and_increment(hstore('"key1"=>"1","key2"=>"1"'), hstore('"key1"=>"1","key2"=>"1","key3"=>"1"'))
```

is:

```
merge_and_increment                  
-------------------------------------
"key1"=>"2", "key2"=>"2", "key3"=>"1"
```

Note that the function will fail miserably if there are values that can't be converted to an integer.

With an insert statement you can use it like this:

```
insert into the_table (id, sum, data)
values (....) 
on conflict (id) do update
   set sum = the_table.sum + excluded.sum, 
       data = merge_and_increment(the_table.data, excluded.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1910076f58b297f1bc368498b6fda504)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_hstore(_old hstore, _new hstore) RETURNS hstore
AS $$
DECLARE
    _out hstore;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        hstore(array_agg(key), array_agg(value::text))
    FROM (
        SELECT
            key,
            SUM(value::int) AS value
        FROM (
            SELECT * FROM each('"key1"=>"1","key2"=>"1"'::hstore)

            UNION ALL

            SELECT * FROM each('"key1"=>"1","key2"=>"1","key3"=>"1"')
        ) s
        GROUP BY key
    ) s
    INTO _out;

    RETURN _out;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

1. `each()` expands the key/value pairs into one row per pair with columns key and value
2. convert type `text` into type `int` and group/sum the `value`s
3. Aggregate into a new `hstore` value using the `hstore(array, array)` function. The array elements are the values of the `key` column and the values of the `value` column.

You can do such an update:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET keyvalue = sum_hstore(keyvalue, '"key1"=>"1","key2"=>"1","key3"=>"1"')
WHERE id = 1;
```